# Opening a Clarity Signpost does not emit its state

Tags: angular, clarity, vmware-clarity

I am using the [Clarity Signposts](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/signposts) and need its state (whether its open or closed). I am using the `*clrIfOpen` structural directive and have assigned it the isOpen variable. `isOpen` is false initially but should update to true when the Signpost is open.

```
<clr-signpost>
    <clr-signpost-content *clrIfOpen="isOpen">
        <p>Signpost Content!</p>
        <span>Signpost State: {{isOpen}}</span>
    </clr-signpost-content>
</clr-signpost>
```

I also tried the `clrIfOpenChange` output on `clrIfOpen` but it too is not triggered when the signpost is opened.

**Clarity Version**: 0.10.0-rc.1

**Plnkr**: https://plnkr.co/edit/OQupObBd9OkJZSpOhpfq?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you want to use is the de-sugared syntax of Angular structural directives to access the Output Emitter.

```
<clr-signpost>
  <ng-template [(clrIfOpen)]="isOpen">
    <clr-signpost-content>
      <p>Signpost Content!</p>
      <span>Signpost State: {{isOpen}}</span>
    </clr-signpost-content>
  </ng-template>
</clr-signpost>
```

Please refer to this Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/SZNDZIiyomGWJsC7UsiC?p=preview